# How can I measure performance of Python code in a hardware independent way?

Tags: python, performance, profiler

I would like to measure the performance of a Python executable in a hardware independent way, ideally I would like to specify a canonical hardware configuration and get the performance metrics for that hardware configuration.

This will allow me to remove one big variability out of performance measurement and make it easy to add it to the CI/CD pipelines and also for developers to have a common benchmark.

If this can be integrated with python profiler then that would be even better.

Comment: Besides artificially slowing down the CPU I don't think there's much hope to become "hardware independent" - why not run the benchmark on always the same CI/CD server? With a VM you can make sure it gets the virtual CPU and RAM specs you specify and as long as each benchmark is comparable with the last one(s) you can infer if the software got faster or slower

Comment: I'm afraid that even for others language, making benchmarks reliable is difficult. This [blog article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/consistent-benchmarking-in-ci/) looks very interesting, and there are some [comments on lobste.rs](https://lobste.rs/s/33xrng/ci_for_performance_reliable). But in general, it's better to stick to the same physical machine, with no other load, and the same perftest procedure.

Comment: Put it simply, this is not possible without assumptions (ie. simplification) of the target script. For example, if the script is compute bound and limited by floating-point arithmetic, then you can predict the performance on many different hardware (this is far more complex than people think due to many low-level details of CPUs). The same applies for the memory throughput. If the script is "generic", then you cannot predict what will be the limitation on the target platform (eg. network, disk latency, etc.). There too many possible execution scenarios. *Performance is always contextual*.